# How can I extrude a dome from a circular face?

Tags: modeling

I have the following mesh:

[image: mesh]

I would like to extrude the face at the center so that a dome forms out of it, such that the dome's boundary would be exactly that of the circle. (Think bubble wrap.)

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, try extruding and scaling it multiple times:

[image]

To help make the extrusions more even, you might try using the *To Sphere* operator (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>). You can define where the center of the "sphere" *To Sphere* uses by using the 3D cursor as the pivot (<kbd>.</kbd>).

If you want to be more precise, try adding a sphere and deleting half, then using *Bridge edge loops* (<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>)

[image]

Note that the number of vertices on the perimeter of the sphere should match the number of vertices around the initial circle.

Answer (score 10):

You can get a dome in the centre without extruding.

1. Add some extra edge loops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
2. Enable [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?%5C#proportional-editing) with falloff set to sphere
3. Lift centre piece up, adjusting falloff size as needed (with scroll wheel or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: That's darn clever.

Answer (score 6):

I would not extrude it. Place your cursor in the center of your object. Add a sphere in the middle and do a boolean modifier.

[image]

Select your original object and set the boolean modifier to union.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem with the boolean modifier is that it nukes your topology.

Comment: @WChargin as long as both objects are made of quads there should be no problems topology wise.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I had never noticed that. It looks like it is fine when both objects are locally exclusively quad-based (that is, there can be tris far away without it affecting the modifier), although the modifier may produce output that includes higher-order (but planar) ngons. Good to know. (Not my downvote, by the way.)