# Extrude curve circularly

Tags: bezier-curves

having consulted [How can I extrude a dome from a circular face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21715/how-can-i-extrude-a-dome-from-a-circular-face), I realize I could probably use that method to achieve what I'm looking for (a stool cushion). However I already have a curve with the wanted form and was wondering if there's something like a circular extrusion.

[image: stool plus curve]

Comment: is it symmetric? if so use the Screw modifier http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28976/how-to-model-the-rounded-outline-of-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the curve and add a screw modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the curve to mesh and then just extruding to the shape you want converting the curve to mesh shortcut is alt+C i think  but maybe there is better way how to do it is long time i use blender